# Unable to import psycopg2 in python using anaconda

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda 2.7 on my desktop and want to connect it to Postgresql server.

I also installed psycopg2 through command prompt and it was successful. But when I import it using Jupyter notebook it shows me the following error.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import psycopg2
>
> C:\Users\amitdarak\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.7.3.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\psycopg2__init__.py
>   in ()
>        48 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
>        49 
>   ---> 50 from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
>        51     BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID,
>        52
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Comment: check your python version from terminal and from your notebook, are they the same? You can also install psycopg2 from jupyter notebook itself. run `!pip install pyscopg2` from a cell and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

`conda install -c anaconda postgresql` worked fine for me on Windows 10.

I know `postgresql` isn't the same module as `psycopg2`, but the easy installation of `postgresql` would trump any advantages `psycopg2` might have for me.